# Convert single-word list to string

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I have a DataFrame column 'stem' with each cell being a single stemmed word inside of a list. I'd like to convert the single-item list to a string, but none of the functions I have seen online have worked. I've tried:

```
    for cell in countdf['stem']:
        cell = str(cell)
```

This doesn't seem to do anything either:

```
    for cell in countdf['stem']:
        cell = ''.join(cell)
```

In both cases, the column/cell types are still 'list' and are printed as ['word'] rather than word.

This one gives me an error 'TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found' :

```
for row in countdf:
      countdf['stem'] = ''.join(countdf['stem'])
```

Following [this link](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-typeerror-sequence-item-0-expected-str-instance-list-found#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20%22TypeError%3A%20sequence%20item,the%20elements%20of%20each%20list.), I've tried:

```
for row in countdf:
      countdf['stem'] = ''.join(''.join(cell) for cell in countdf['stem'])
```

But this throws a memory error. This shouldn't be a memory-intensive process, so there must be something wrong here as well.

I know I'm applying the right operations here since these are the only ones being recommended anywhere, but surely there must be some issue in *how* I'm applying it. I'm genuinely lost here and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: don't use loops in pandas dataframes. you're operating on copies of the values, so pandas has no idea you want to include them back in the dataframe. Use pandas' `Series.str` methods instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you can just use `.str`:

```
countdf['stem'] = countdf['stem'].str[0]
```

This is simple so it will be very fast. :)

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can use `apply`

```
countdf['stem'] = countdf['stem'].apply(''.join)
```

If your column value contains integer

```py
countdf['stem'] = countdf['stem'].apply(lambda lst: ''.join(map(str, lst)))
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to learn some more about when to use ```apply```. For some reason that's never really clicked for me.